# increasing image quality of treeview icons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview that contains icons. The icons are ugly. and by ugly i mean low quality. and by low quality i mean something i would expect to see from a dos program

i would hope there would be a way to improve the image quality of the icons, but after looking around on microsoft's development site, I have yet to find a solution.

to be honest, at this point i don't even know what to look for. 'image quality' is very too broad of a phrase to search for (i've gotten very random results from google searches).

i am using an `ImageList` to store these icons in the `TreeView`. there really isnt much code to show that would be of use here - at least i dont think so.

sorry for the boring question.

Comment: You didn't document the ImageList.ColorDepth and ImageSize property values you used.  So that's probably the cause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.colordepth.aspx

The default value is set to 8-bit, so changing this property of your list will probably help. Essentially, just add the following line to your code:

```
imagelist.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
```

Comment: I tried that (well, setting it in the Designer properties), but the actual final icons on the tree view have reduced colours nonetheless...

Answer (score -3):

It can be improved. What you need to do is to open it in photoshop or gimp and resample it at 3 times it size. Then resample it at 600 dpi and resize it down to 8 x 10.
Notice, that I specified to resize and not down size. You click on the pic and the corners have a handle for you to click on and size it down to the appropraite size. This way, the pixels are closer together.

Then, you use a very soft blur, I mean really soft. The secret is when it is printed. We print at 600 to 1200 dpi which is what will enhance the picture and that is what a printer has to keep in mind. When you print on glossy paper at 600 dpi, the pic comes out really nice and sharp.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant. He's not dealing with images or trying to print them.

Comment: The original image quality is fine actually. When the image is loaded/added to the `ImageList` it looks terrible. So that leads me to believe that it's something going wrong in actual code.

Comment: That too... where did printing come from?

Comment: This guy has been posting largely irrelevant answers all over the place. Not sure what he's on.